Can iPhones create a AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession with .external devices
With iOS 17, we saw the introduction of using external cameras on iPads. We can get these external cameras as AVCaptureDevices via AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.external], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified). We also see that the documentation for AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.external mentions that

On iPad, external devices are those that conform to the UVC (USB Video Class) specification.

When running a project using the above code on an iPad, I do see this external camera feed when adding the device as an input to an AVCaptureSession. However, when running the same project on an iPhone 15 Pro running iOS 17+, the external device does not show up in the AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.
Can we assume, or do we know for a fact, that there is no way to create a AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession with .external devices on iPhones?

It sounds like you have answered your own question - The documentation you reference mentions iPads explicitly and you tried it on an iPhone and it didn't work.

@Paulw11 I mean, the documentation does explicitly mention iPads but doesn't explicitly mention that it only works on iPads. And I wasn't sure if it wasn't working on iPhone because our iPhone has a USB-C 3 port and the webcam we are using has a USB-C 2 cord. That's a gap in my knowledge of USB-C.

iPads support driver kit and iPhones do not. As I understand it, Apple changed the iPhone to usb-c for charging because of the EU regulations. They have not implemented any additional peripheral support beyond what was supported by lightning at this point.

Ah, thank you @paulw11, that answers my question a lot more. That's a good point about Apple never intending to support USB-C on iPhone and sort of having their hand forced by EU.
